# Can't build kubernetes-certbot docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

There is container for using certbot in kubernetes.
https://hub.docker.com/r/choffmeister/kubernetes-certbot/

It uses 1.3.0 release. I want to build same docker image, but with latest version 1.10.2.
I just replaced version in file, and when i try to build image, it exit with error:

```
    Step 1/9 : FROM debian:8.1
     ---> 73fe606256a5
    Step 2/9 : MAINTAINER *** <***>
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 0d91ae291e44
    Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get update &&   apt-get install ---yes git wget &&   apt-get clean &&   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 2192a26717c9
    Step 4/9 : RUN git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot /opt/certbot &&   ln -s /opt/certbot/letsencrypt-auto /usr/local/bin/letsencrypt-auto &&   letsencrypt-auto; exit 0
     ---> Using cache
     ---> e5e4082a2e72
    Step 5/9 : RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.10.2/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl &&   chmod +x kubectl &&   mv kubectl /usr/local/bin
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 3159428e91d3
    Step 6/9 : WORKDIR /opt/kubernetes-certbot
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 71eb2643ce9f
    Step 7/9 : COPY run.sh ./run.sh
    lstat run.sh: no such file or directory
```

Same problem when i try to build same Dockerfile from https://github.com/choffmeister/kubernetes-certbot/blob/master/Dockerfile.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the run.sh file is not available. Can you confirm that file is in the same folder as the Dockerfile? Here is the link to the run.sh file:
https://github.com/choffmeister/kubernetes-certbot/blob/master/run.sh

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!